# How to replace HashMap<String, Integer> with an array?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have a program that count occurrences of words in given array. It keeps words and its quantity. For example, in  given array:

```
String array[] = {"cat", "dog", "cat"};
```

I have 2 cats, and 1 dog. Making it with HashMap is quite simple:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < wordarray.length; i++) {
    String word = wordarray[i].toLowerCase();
    if (map.containsKey(word)) {
        map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
    } else {
        map.put(word, 1);
    }
}
```

Then I just need to print it out:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

But is there any way to make it without `HashMap` only using arrays of objects?

Comment: Two dimensions array??

Comment: The reason why a HashMap is used is because it has unique keys like a Set. This way you can check if the String you are looking for exists, without having to loop over an entire Array.

Comment: Implement/reuse hash table with open addressing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom class to hold your string and int values, and then use an array to hold them. In pseudo-code:

```
class Myclass
 public int myInt;
 public string MyString;
 //Constructor omited..


//Somewhere else..
MyClass[] my = new Myclass[2];
my[0] = new MyClass("string", 1);
```

Comment: nice one :) I will try it!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a list/array of Map.Entry key/value pairs.

There's already a method to do it for you in `HashMap`: `entrySet()`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet()

Comment: Nope, that's lazy - a quality in the best programmers.

Answer (score 1):

This much-much slower than using `HashMap`, but it should work:

Let's say, you sure that no word occurs in your text more than `N` times (as a upper bound you can choose total number of words in text). Then you can allocate array of that size `N` of ArrayList elements: `a = new ArrayList[N]; for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) a[i] = new ArrayList<String>();`

Then, for every word `w`, you will iterate over that array, find the cell with index `c` with `ArrayList<String>` which contains `w` and move `w` from `c` to `c+1` (using `list.remove(Object)` and `list.add(Object)`). If no cell found, add `w` to the list in the first cell: `a[0].add(w)`.

Some optimizations:

- use `HashSet` in array instead of `ArrayList`, though it looks inappropriate in your case;
- use array of arrays of `[N][N]` size. There will be more memory consumption, but less time spent.

Answer (score 1):

you can check the implementation of Map using arrays. Here is a nice [article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaDatastructures/article.html#map) about this